# Не работают перенаправления

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

делаю на сайте страницу с профилями, но с линками такая проблема

При переходе на 
Сайт/profile/nickname выдает 404

Но если ник состоит из цифр, то все работает

Пытался через исправить через .htaccess перебробывал кучу правил, так ничего и не получилось. Единственное выдавало не 404, а переходило на

Сайт/profile/?nick=nickname

но меня такой вариант не устраивает.

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: Да, я находил и пытался например так 


    function do_rewrite(){

     add_rewrite_rule( '^(profile)/([^/]*)/?', '?nick=$matches[1]', 'top' ); 

    }

Comment: Через сайт/profile/?nick=nickname работает, но сайт/profile/nickname нет

Comment: После добавления add_rewrite_rule() сохраняли структуру постоянных ссылок в админке?

Comment: Да, сохранял и проверял в самом файлике

Comment: Это должно помочь, что-то вы неправильно делаете

Comment: Для ников из цифр все работает, но с обычными никами просто 404, я хз что еще может быть. Может нужно что то дополнительно настраивать? 
У меня создана страница для profile, а для самих профилей конечно нет